# Mellin transform and Rayleigh distributions

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, mellin-transform

As a part of compound channel analysis I would like to get some help in finding out the Mellin transform of product pdf of two Rayleigh distributions.

I have reached at a situation

$$F(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)dx.$$

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is encouraged to learn Latex & MathJax typesetting. It will probably increase the chance to get positive responses.

Comment: with $x =(y/a)^{1/2}, dx = \frac{y^{-1/2}}{2 a^{1/2}}$  $$F(s) = C\int_0^\infty x^{s} e^{-a x^2} dx= \frac{C}{2} a^{-1/2-s/2}\int_0^\infty y^{s/2-1/2} e^{- y} dy =  \frac{C}{2} a^{-(s+1)/2} \Gamma((s+1)/2)$$

Comment: Welcome in our [tex tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you can learn how write nice formulas, also if you do right mouse button over a formula,  choosing Show Maths as>TEX Commands> then you can see the code, and use dollars to write a formula quickly. Also you have an online editor of TEX, that is http://www.texpaste.com Good luck.

Comment: what is the value of C here?  Can both constants 'a' and 'C' come along in the same equation?

Comment: $2^{\frac{s-1}{2}} \left(\frac{1}{\text{Sigma}^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)$